# Google Maps API on SquareSpace - Uncaught TypeError

Tags: google-maps-api-3, squarespace

I am trying to keep an old Squarespace 5 site afloat before switching over to a new site, and the Google Map has stopped placing markers on a map that used to work fine (I have not changed anything recently). I can reproduce the error creating a map-test page (http://ncbirdingtrail.org/map-test)

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="height:350px;width:100%"></div>
<script>

  function initMap() {
    var myLatLng = {lat: 35, lng: -79};
    console.log(document.getElementById('map_canvas'));
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      center: myLatLng,
      zoom:8
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
    });

  }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=AIzaSyDHGo3qFRpz1BGcH6zGcNyqWC6FB3C9Q4g&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

This produces the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$' of undefined
at VR.C (marker.js:69)
at Object.Va (global.js?CE=75:1)
at map.js:5
at new Yr (map.js:4)
at $r (map.js:5)
at as (map.js:6)
at _.pl.Db (map.js:59)
at Ct (map.js:41)
at map.js:43
```

However, if I make a simple web page from this html, it works fine. If I do not include the marker code, the error only appears once.

Comment: Try specifying a version other than the weekly version:   [Versioning](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions) (I'm not sure what `v=3` gives you these days, I don't see it mentioned in the documentation anymore, but I might have missed it).  You might also look at ["an update affected my application"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions#an-update-affected-my-application) to see if that helps.

Comment: The page you link to is running v3.34.16 of the API, so you might want to try v=3.33 or v=3.35, to see if either of those help.

Comment: This could be due to a conflict between your code and the YUI library that Squarespace 5 is using via `yahoo-dom-event.js`. By blocking that resource using dev. tools in Chrome, the map pin will display (albeit with additional, unrelated console errors due to YUI no longer being present). This makes sense if indeed your code works when outside of the Squarespace/YUI environment. The nature of the conflict and how to fix it -- that I do not know. This could also be coincidence only.

Comment: Thanks to you both. Yes, I've tried several versions just to make sure with similar results.

Comment: The YUI library thing is promising. My main page works properly without it...Thank you Brandon! Now just to figure out how to make it work...